# When I tried to downlaod gym[box2d] , I got this error "metadata_generation_failed"

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to install gym[box2d] but I got hit with this error.

[image]

I have tried to upgrade and downgrade wheel and setuptools and that didn't work.

I deleted all the packages and installed them again hoping something will work but still the same error appeared.